# Bootstrap Navbar: navbar-brand intendation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, input, navbar

I have two Bootstrap navbars which follow each other on the page. The setup looks like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    <a class="navbar-brand" style="color:white" href="#">
        Search
    </a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <div class="navbar-form navbar-left">
            <div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        //Here are some inputs
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    <a class="navbar-brand" style="color:white" href="#">
        Filter
    </a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <div class="navbar-form navbar-left">
            <div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        //Here are some inputs
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        //Here are some inputs
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Because `"Search"` and `"Filter"` are of different length, the inputs start at a different location. I would like to symmetrically start with the inputs on both navbars (cp. the red arrows in the picture).

My initial attempt to specify the `width` of `navbar-brand` by a percentage doesn't work, because it causes the inputs to overlap the brand in case of resizing the window.

I really appreciate any help!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap? Also `row` is *only* used to contain `col-*` not other things like `form-group`

Comment: @Zim I'm working with Bootstrap v3.3.7. Do you know a workaround?